# Unable to get property 'defaultView'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery 1.12.2 and sometimes I encoutered the error `Unable to get property 'defaultView' of undefined or null reference`.

The error occured at this line :

```
if (jQuery(event.target).is('[contenteditable]') ||
    jQuery(event.target).css('position') == 'absolute' ||
    jQuery(event.target).css('position') == 'fixed') {
        return;
}
```

**Edit**
This is on document mousedown event.

```
jQuery(document).bind('mousedown', function (event) {

            var $active_element;
            if (jQuery(event.target).parents(".ui-draggable").length > 0) {
                if (jQuery(event.target).parents(".ui-draggable").parent().data('contentbuilder')) {
                    $active_element = jQuery(event.target).parents(".ui-draggable").parent(); //Get current Builder element
                }
            }

            //Remove Overlay on embedded object to enable the object.
            if (jQuery(event.target).attr("class") == 'ovl') {
                jQuery(event.target).css('z-index', '-1');
            }

            (...)

            if (jQuery(event.target).is('[contenteditable]') ||
                jQuery(event.target).css('position') == 'absolute' ||
                jQuery(event.target).css('position') == 'fixed'
            ) {
                return;
            }

            jQuery(event.target).parents().each(function (e) {

                if (jQuery(this).is('[contenteditable]') ||
                    jQuery(this).css('position') == 'absolute' ||
                    jQuery(this).css('position') == 'fixed'
                ) {
                    return;
                }

            });

           (...)

}
```

I think it isn't in the .each() function but maybe ?
It comes from `getComputedStyle()` fucnction...

Can you help me ?

Comment: Share the complete code, What is `event`?

Comment: `event` might not be what you think it is in this context, we can't know for sure unless you share more.

Comment: I added the function with the event param.

Comment: please debug your code and check what comes in (jQuery(this).is('[contenteditable]' ) this keyword ?

Comment: This event occured rarely and only on Edge... So I can't reproduce it manually. I don't know how and when it comes.